# Postgres Case-Insensitive search for Jsonb column tag keys

Tags: postgresql, query, json, case-sensitive

I have a requirement to obtain the rows which match given tags key and value case-insensitively.

**Here:** Key search should be case insensitive and values may be String or Array of String.

Right Now, I am using following Query :

Database : **Postgres**

`select * from my_table_name where jsonb_contains(lower(to_jsonb(jsonb_extract_path(tags,'key1'))::TEXT)::jsonb, to_jsonb('"value1"'::jsonb))`

But it is searching key as case sensitive manner.

For Example:
above query should return all records having key is (key1,Key1,KEY1) and value is 'Value1'
Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over all key/value pairs in order to compare them using `lower()`

Something along the lines:

```
select mt.*
from my_table_name mt
where exists (select * 
              from jsonb_each_text(mt.tags) as t(tag, value) 
              where lower(t.tag) = 'key1'
                and lower(t.value) = 'value1');
```

This assumes your column `tags` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's a `json` you need to use `json_each_text()` instead.

Comment: Thank a lots !!! It works for me partially.

This query will not return records having  value is ["value1"].

Like my records are stored in Jsonb like :  
{
    "KEY2": [ "VALUE1" ]
}

Answer (score 2):

Using the JSONPATH query language, you could query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table_name
WHERE jsonb_path_match(
         tags,
         '$.keyvalue().key like_regex "^key1$" flag "i" && $.keyvalue().value like_regex "^value1$" flag "i"'
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Laurenz!!